# How to use a regex to extract this from a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a huge list of links like these:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1" class="srTtl2a">Here is the name</a>
```

And I want to keep the *main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx* and the *Here is the name*

How to do this? I can use PHP or Notepad++

Thank you

Comment: `//a[@class="srTtl2a"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex to get things going although I wouldn't really recommend it.
Using the parse_url function provided by Bijay Rai, the following piece of code does the job.

**PHP Example:**

```
<?php
    $subject = "<a href=\"http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1\" class=\"srTtl2a\">Here is the name</a><a href=\"http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1\" class=\"srTtl2a\">Here is the name</a><a href=\"http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1\" class=\"srTtl2a\">sdasdas</a>";
    $pattern = '/\<a\shref=\"(.+?)\"\s.+?\>(.+?)\<\/a\>/';

    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    //print_r($matches);

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        echo "Url: " . $match[1] . "\n";
        echo "Path: " . parse_url($match[1], PHP_URL_PATH) . "\n";
        echo "Title: " . $match[2] . "\n\n";
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Url: http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1
Path: /main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx
Title: Here is the name

Url: http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1
Path: /main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx
Title: Here is the name

Url: http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1
Path: /main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx
Title: sdasdas
```

[Ideone Example](http://ideone.com/QiD5DU)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url="http://www.domain.com/main/1,1,51,463-Here_Goes_A_Name.aspx?shmod=1";
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $host;?>
```

[Output](https://eval.in/170441)

Comment: I have a huge list of the format in my question though. This does not get the name also